# Programmatic control of virtual desktops in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10

I love that Windows 10 now has support for virtual desktops built in, but I have some features that I'd like to add/modify (e.g., force a window to appear on all desktops, launch the task view with a hotkey, have per-monitor desktops, etc.)

I have searched for applications and developer references to help me customize my desktops, but I have had no luck.

Where should I start? I am looking for Windows API functions (ideally, that are callable from a C# application) that will give me programmatic access to manipulate virtual desktops and the windows therein.

Comment: You're going to really like this app....https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Programmatic access to the virtual desktop feature is very limited, as Microsoft has only exposed the [IVirtualDesktopManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager) COM interface. It does provide two key functions:

- `IVirtualDesktopManager::GetWindowDesktopId` allows you to retrieve the ID of a virtual desktop, based on a window that is already assigned to that desktop.
- `IVirtualDesktopManager::MoveWindowToDesktop` allows you to move a window to a specific virtual desktop.

Unfortunately, this is not nearly enough to accomplish anything useful. I've written some C# code based on the reverse-engineering work done by [NickoTin](http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/105416/blog3671.html).  I can't read much of the Russian in his blog post, but his C++ code was pretty accurate.

I do need to emphasize that this code is not something you want to commit to in a product.  Microsoft always feels free to change undocumented APIs whenever they feel like it.  And there is a runtime risk as well: this code does not necessarily interact well when the user is tinkering with the virtual desktops.  Always keep in mind that a virtual desktop can appear and disappear at any time, completely out of sync with your code.

To use the code, create a new C# class library project.  I'll first post ComInterop.cs, it contains the COM interface declarations that match NickoTin's C++ declarations:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Windows10Interop {
    internal static class Guids {
        public static readonly Guid CLSID_ImmersiveShell = 
            new Guid(0xC2F03A33, 0x21F5, 0x47FA, 0xB4, 0xBB, 0x15, 0x63, 0x62, 0xA2, 0xF2, 0x39);
        public static readonly Guid CLSID_VirtualDesktopManagerInternal = 
            new Guid(0xC5E0CDCA, 0x7B6E, 0x41B2, 0x9F, 0xC4, 0xD9, 0x39, 0x75, 0xCC, 0x46, 0x7B);
        public static readonly Guid CLSID_VirtualDesktopManager = 
            new Guid("AA509086-5CA9-4C25-8F95-589D3C07B48A");
        public static readonly Guid IID_IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal = 
            new Guid("AF8DA486-95BB-4460-B3B7-6E7A6B2962B5");
        public static readonly Guid IID_IVirtualDesktop = 
            new Guid("FF72FFDD-BE7E-43FC-9C03-AD81681E88E4");
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("FF72FFDD-BE7E-43FC-9C03-AD81681E88E4")]
    internal interface IVirtualDesktop {
        void notimpl1(); // void IsViewVisible(IApplicationView view, out int visible);
        Guid GetId();
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("AF8DA486-95BB-4460-B3B7-6E7A6B2962B5")]
    internal interface IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal {
        int GetCount();
        void notimpl1();  // void MoveViewToDesktop(IApplicationView view, IVirtualDesktop desktop);
        void notimpl2();  // void CanViewMoveDesktops(IApplicationView view, out int itcan);
        IVirtualDesktop GetCurrentDesktop();
        void GetDesktops(out IObjectArray desktops);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetAdjacentDesktop(IVirtualDesktop from, int direction, out IVirtualDesktop desktop);
        void SwitchDesktop(IVirtualDesktop desktop);
        IVirtualDesktop CreateDesktop();
        void RemoveDesktop(IVirtualDesktop desktop, IVirtualDesktop fallback);
        IVirtualDesktop FindDesktop(ref Guid desktopid);
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("a5cd92ff-29be-454c-8d04-d82879fb3f1b")]
    internal interface IVirtualDesktopManager {
        int IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(IntPtr topLevelWindow);
        Guid GetWindowDesktopId(IntPtr topLevelWindow);
        void MoveWindowToDesktop(IntPtr topLevelWindow, ref Guid desktopId);
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("92CA9DCD-5622-4bba-A805-5E9F541BD8C9")]
    internal interface IObjectArray {
        void GetCount(out int count);
        void GetAt(int index, ref Guid iid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]out object obj);
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
    internal interface IServiceProvider10 {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
        object QueryService(ref Guid service, ref Guid riid);
    }

}
```

Next is Desktop.cs. It contains the friendly C# classes that you can use in your code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Windows10Interop
{
    public class Desktop {
        public static int Count {
            // Returns the number of desktops
            get { return DesktopManager.Manager.GetCount(); }
        }

        public static Desktop Current {
            // Returns current desktop
            get { return new Desktop(DesktopManager.Manager.GetCurrentDesktop()); }
        }

        public static Desktop FromIndex(int index) {
            // Create desktop object from index 0..Count-1
            return new Desktop(DesktopManager.GetDesktop(index));
        }

        public static Desktop FromWindow(IntPtr hWnd) {
            // Creates desktop object on which window <hWnd> is displayed
            Guid id = DesktopManager.WManager.GetWindowDesktopId(hWnd);
            return new Desktop(DesktopManager.Manager.FindDesktop(ref id));
        }

        public static Desktop Create() {
            // Create a new desktop
            return new Desktop(DesktopManager.Manager.CreateDesktop());
        }

        public void Remove(Desktop fallback = null) {
            // Destroy desktop and switch to <fallback>
            var back = fallback == null ? DesktopManager.GetDesktop(0) : fallback.itf;
            DesktopManager.Manager.RemoveDesktop(itf, back);
        }

        public bool IsVisible {
            // Returns <true> if this desktop is the current displayed one
            get { return object.ReferenceEquals(itf, DesktopManager.Manager.GetCurrentDesktop()); }
        }

        public void MakeVisible() {
            // Make this desktop visible
            DesktopManager.Manager.SwitchDesktop(itf);
        }

        public Desktop Left {
            // Returns desktop at the left of this one, null if none
            get {
                IVirtualDesktop desktop;
                int hr = DesktopManager.Manager.GetAdjacentDesktop(itf, 3, out desktop);
                if (hr == 0) return new Desktop(desktop);
                else return null;

            }
        }

        public Desktop Right {
            // Returns desktop at the right of this one, null if none
            get {
                IVirtualDesktop desktop;
                int hr = DesktopManager.Manager.GetAdjacentDesktop(itf, 4, out desktop);
                if (hr == 0) return new Desktop(desktop);
                else return null;
            }
        }

        public void MoveWindow(IntPtr handle) {
            // Move window <handle> to this desktop
            DesktopManager.WManager.MoveWindowToDesktop(handle, itf.GetId());
        }

        public bool HasWindow(IntPtr handle) {
            // Returns true if window <handle> is on this desktop
            return itf.GetId() == DesktopManager.WManager.GetWindowDesktopId(handle);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return itf.GetHashCode();
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            var desk = obj as Desktop;
            return desk != null && object.ReferenceEquals(this.itf, desk.itf);
        }

        private IVirtualDesktop itf;
        private Desktop(IVirtualDesktop itf) { this.itf = itf; }
    }

    internal static class DesktopManager {
        static DesktopManager() {
            var shell = (IServiceProvider10)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guids.CLSID_ImmersiveShell));
            Manager = (IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal)shell.QueryService(Guids.CLSID_VirtualDesktopManagerInternal, Guids.IID_IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal);
            WManager = (IVirtualDesktopManager)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guids.CLSID_VirtualDesktopManager));
        }

        internal static IVirtualDesktop GetDesktop(int index) {
            int count = Manager.GetCount();
            if (index < 0 || index >= count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            IObjectArray desktops;
            Manager.GetDesktops(out desktops);
            object objdesk;
            desktops.GetAt(index, Guids.IID_IVirtualDesktop, out objdesk);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(desktops);
            return (IVirtualDesktop)objdesk;
        }

        internal static IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal Manager;
        internal static IVirtualDesktopManager WManager;
    }
}
```

And finally a little test WinForms project that I used to test the code.  Just drop 4 buttons on a form and name them buttonLeft/Right/Create/Destroy:

```
using Windows10Interop;
using System.Diagnostics;
...
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var curr = Desktop.FromWindow(this.Handle);
            Debug.Assert(curr.Equals(Desktop.Current));
            var right = curr.Right;
            if (right == null) right = Desktop.FromIndex(0);
            if (right != null) {
                right.MoveWindow(this.Handle);
                right.MakeVisible();
                this.BringToFront();
                Debug.Assert(right.IsVisible);
            }
        }

        private void buttonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var curr = Desktop.FromWindow(this.Handle);
            Debug.Assert(curr.Equals(Desktop.Current));
            var left = curr.Left;
            if (left == null) left = Desktop.FromIndex(Desktop.Count - 1);
            if (left != null) {
                left.MoveWindow(this.Handle);
                left.MakeVisible();
                this.BringToFront();
                Debug.Assert(left.IsVisible);
            } 
        }

        private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var desk = Desktop.Create();
            desk.MoveWindow(this.Handle);
            desk.MakeVisible();
            Debug.Assert(desk.IsVisible);
            Debug.Assert(desk.Equals(Desktop.Current));
        }

        private void buttonDestroy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var curr = Desktop.FromWindow(this.Handle);
            var next = curr.Left;
            if (next == null) next = curr.Right;
            if (next != null && next != curr) {
                next.MoveWindow(this.Handle);
                curr.Remove(next);
                Debug.Assert(next.IsVisible);
            }
        }
    }
```

The only real quirk I noticed while testing this is that moving a window from one desktop to another can move it to the bottom of the Z-order when you *first* switch the desktop, then move the window.  No such problem if you do it the other way around.

Comment: When calling to `public static int Count` in `class Desktop`

Outer: The type initializer for 'Windows10Interop.DesktopManager' threw an exception.

Inner: Specified cast is not valid. {System.InvalidCastException}

I am honestly kind of lost in that code. Help appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop/issues/20

Comment: Does it work for anyone¿ I get this exception `Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Windows10Interop.DesktopManager' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` for this line `Manager = (IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal) shell.QueryService(Guids.CLSID_VirtualDesktopManagerInternal, Guids.IID_IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal);`

Comment: I get the same error. I think some Guids have changed over time? But I am not quite sure at the moment.

Comment: It works when I replace all occurrences of VirtualDesktopManagerInternal guid to "F31574D6-B682-4CDC-BD56-1827860ABEC6" which is searched from https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/206559-virtual-desktop-manager-under-windows-10/

Answer (score 45):

The [Windows SDK Support Team Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/) posted a [C# demo to switch Desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/virtual-desktop-switching-in-windows-10) via IVirtualDesktopManager:

```cs
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("a5cd92ff-29be-454c-8d04-d82879fb3f1b")]
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public interface IVirtualDesktopManager
{
[PreserveSig]
int IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(
    [In] IntPtr TopLevelWindow,
    [Out] out int OnCurrentDesktop
    );
[PreserveSig]
int GetWindowDesktopId(
    [In] IntPtr TopLevelWindow,
    [Out] out Guid CurrentDesktop
    );

[PreserveSig]
int MoveWindowToDesktop(
    [In] IntPtr TopLevelWindow,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    [In]Guid CurrentDesktop
    );
}

[ComImport, Guid("aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a")]
public class CVirtualDesktopManager
{

}
public class VirtualDesktopManager
{
    public VirtualDesktopManager()
    {
        cmanager = new CVirtualDesktopManager();
        manager = (IVirtualDesktopManager)cmanager;
    }
    ~VirtualDesktopManager()
    {
        manager = null;
        cmanager = null;
    }
    private CVirtualDesktopManager cmanager = null;
    private IVirtualDesktopManager manager;

    public bool IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(IntPtr TopLevelWindow)
    {
        int result;
        int hr;
        if ((hr = manager.IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(TopLevelWindow, out result)) != 0)
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        return result != 0;
    }

    public Guid GetWindowDesktopId(IntPtr TopLevelWindow)
    {
        Guid result;
        int hr;
        if ((hr = manager.GetWindowDesktopId(TopLevelWindow, out result)) != 0)
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void MoveWindowToDesktop(IntPtr TopLevelWindow, Guid CurrentDesktop)
    {
        int hr;
        if ((hr = manager.MoveWindowToDesktop(TopLevelWindow, CurrentDesktop)) != 0)
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
    }
}
```

it includes the API to detect on which desktop the Window is shown and it can switch and move a Windows the a Desktop.

Comment: Kinda makes you wonder why Microsoft didn't just add a keyboard shortcut for this directly doesn't it...

Comment: This is excellent thank you. If you would like to find the GUIDs for your desktops, you can look in the registry here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops\Desktops

Answer (score 19):

There is this guy that made a application to map keyboard shorcut to move a window between virtual desktop.
https://github.com/Grabacr07/SylphyHorn
(I use it every day )

He has a blog where he explain what he did
http://grabacr.net/archives/5701 ( you can use google translate it is in japanese)

He in fact used the same api mantionned in the Alberto Tostado response.
http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/105416/blog3671.html 
and the api can be found on his github https://github.com/Grabacr07/VirtualDesktop

The api is really simple to use BUT it seems impossible to move a window from another process.

```
public static bool MoveToDesktop(IntPtr hWnd, VirtualDesktop virtualDesktop)
    {
        ThrowIfNotSupported();

        int processId;
        NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);

        if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id == processId)  // THAT LINE
        {
            var guid = virtualDesktop.Id;
            VirtualDesktop.ComManager.MoveWindowToDesktop(hWnd, ref guid);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

To workaround this problem they made another implementation that they use alongside the one in the russian blog

```
if (VirtualDesktopHelper.MoveToDesktop(hWnd, right) //<- the one in the russian blog
                    || this.helper.MoveWindowToDesktop(hWnd, right.Id)) <- the second implementation
```

The second implementation can be found here:  https://github.com/tmyt/VDMHelper
This one can move a window from another process to another desktop. BUT it is buggy right now. For exemple when i try to move some window like google chrome it crash.

So this is the result of my research. I m rigth now trying to make a StickyWindow feature with these api.

Comment: I would like to do something even more simple than moving windows, just to switch desktops.. How would I do that? I'm very frustrated by the lack of a return to previous desktop key, that would be the most useful thing ever - and by the lack of direct desktop keys - e.g. like win-ctrl-1 to go to desktop 1 - so I'd like to write an autoit script to make those keys

Comment: Yes this is really simple to implement!
There is this project: https://github.com/nullpo-head/Windows-10-Virtual-Desktop-Switching-Shortcut 
that does exacly that
But i would suggest you to just customize the code from this project( https://github.com/Grabacr07/SylphyHorn) to your needs. It has a better implementation.

Comment: @ycomp I made a DLL that is accessible from AutoHotkey https://github.com/Ciantic/VirtualDesktopAccessor

Comment: @ycomp this is something you'll like....https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 7):

I fear that all about "Virtual desktops" in Windows 10 is undocumented, but in a Russian page I've seen documented the interfaces. I don't speak Russian but seems that they have used reversed engineering. Anyway, the code is very clear (Thanks to them!).

Keep an eye here:
    http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/105416/blog3671.html

I've been trying to see if the old API's CreateDesktop, OpenDesktop, etc... is linked to the new Virtual-Desktops, but no way...

The interfaces work with the final production release of Windows 10 (2015-05-08), but you shouldn't use them in a real wide distributed application until Microsoft documents them. Too much risk.

Regards.

Comment: [It is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, there is some documentation for an interface. But how do you use it inside a "normal" UWP App using c#/xaml?? Can you give any examples of that?

Comment: @okieh look at my answer. Microsoft created a C# demo

Comment: The CLSIDs are no longer valid.

Comment: @okieh Did you ever find out how to do it? I'd very much like to spawn a new window if someone clicks a notification while being on a virtual desktop that does not yet have an open window

Comment: [IVirtualDesktopManager is documented in Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager)

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the virtual desktop GUIDs from the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops
```

To supplement magicandre1981's excellent answer above, you may need to know the desktops in advance and their related Guids without knowing which TopWindow is on which desktop.

An example how to do this.
First I create a class to hold the information for each virtual desktop:

```
public class VirtualDesktop
{
    public byte[] VirtualDesktopId { get; set; }
    public Guid VirtualDesktopGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Wallpaper { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentVirtualDesktop { get; set; }
}
```

Then here is an example method to fill a List of VirtualDesktop instances:

```
public static List<VirtualDesktop> EnumerateVirtualDesktops()
{
    List<VirtualDesktop> virtualDesktops = new List<VirtualDesktop>();
    //get ids from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops,VirtualDesktopIDs
    //assume byte length is # of VDesktops * 16
    byte[] virtualDesktopIDs = (byte[])Registry.GetValue(
            keyName: @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops",
            valueName: "VirtualDesktopIDs",
            defaultValue: new byte[0]
        );
    byte[] currentVirtualDesktop = (byte[])Registry.GetValue(
            keyName: @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops",
            valueName: "CurrentVirtualDesktop",
            defaultValue: new byte[0]
        );
    int numberOfVirtualDesktops = virtualDesktopIDs.Length / 16;
    for (int iVD = 0; iVD < numberOfVirtualDesktops; iVD++)
    {
        byte[] virtualDesktopID = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(
                sourceArray: virtualDesktopIDs,
                sourceIndex: iVD * 16,
                destinationArray: virtualDesktopID,
                destinationIndex: 0,
                length: 16
            );
        Guid virtualDesktopGuid = new Guid(virtualDesktopID);
        //keys for each virtual desktop
        string virtualDesktopName = (string)Registry.GetValue(
                keyName: String.Format(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops\Desktops\{0:B}", virtualDesktopGuid),
                valueName: "Name",
                defaultValue: ""
            );
        //You should handle null here, which means the desktop key doesn't exist, which never happens in my use-case
        if (virtualDesktopName == "")
        {
            virtualDesktopName = String.Format("Desktop {0}", iVD + 1);
        }
        string virtualDesktopWallpaper = (string)Registry.GetValue(
                keyName: String.Format(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops\Desktops\{0:B}", virtualDesktopGuid),
                valueName: "Wallpaper",
                defaultValue: ""
            );
        virtualDesktops.Add(new VirtualDesktop()
        {
            VirtualDesktopId = virtualDesktopID,
            VirtualDesktopGuid = virtualDesktopGuid,
            Name = virtualDesktopName,
            Wallpaper = virtualDesktopWallpaper,
            IsCurrentVirtualDesktop = virtualDesktopID.SequenceEqual(currentVirtualDesktop)
        });
    }
    return virtualDesktops;
}
```

Then you can happily move your windows around to specific desktops using the Windows API MoveWindowToDesktop function as in magicandre1981's answer.
E.g.

```
MoveWindowToDesktop(TopLevelWindow, virtualDesktops.First(vd => vd.Name == "Desktop 1").VirtualDesktopGuid)
```