# Java get desktop number the user is on

Tags: java, windows

The "desktop" I am talking about is the one you create (on windows) when clicking Ctrl + Windows + D (the "desktop number" is the number you see above the desktop when you click Task View)

I'm making a small Java program and I need to be able to get the current desktop number (specifically, I need to know whether the user is on the 1st desktop or not)

It's a small program, so simple answers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717999/how-to-get-list-of-all-window-handles-in-java-using-jna. I think you can refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure Java method to do this, and it's impossible to write one, so you'll need to use JNI for this. If you have a window on the current virtual desktop, then you can use the documented public API: [GetWindowDesktopId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager-getwindowdesktopid). If you don't, you'll have to use `GetCurrentDesktop` inside of `IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal`, as explained by [Altering Win10 virtual desktop behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416843/altering-win10-virtual-desktop-behavior/32417530#32417530).