# Enumerating window handles including virtual desktops

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10-desktop

I've been using the particularly handy [EnumWindows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) to collect the handles of currently open windows.  Unfortunately, this function only picks up handles from the current desktop - if I open a new virtual desktop and open windows there, only the currently shown desktop's windows will be enumerated.

The Windows virtual desktop API docs seem pretty thin on the ground - does anyone know of a solution that would let me pick up window handles from all open windows across all virtual desktops?

Comment: Create a process on that virtual desktop and enumerate windows there

Comment: Not sure this works - EnumWindows literally gets handles from whatever desktop is currently visible, no matter what process it's running from

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Each process has an affinity with a desktop and when you do things like `EnumWindows`, `FindWindow` etc., that operates in the desktop to which the process is associated.

Comment: The new Win10 virtual desktop feature is hard to use programmatically, Microsoft chose to intentionally not document the COM interfaces.  A Russian programmer reverse-engineered it, you can see a C# version of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417530/17034).  Still not exactly what you want, no enumeration for windows, but you can enumerate desktops and switch to them so EnumWindows would see them.