# C# WindowsForm - Change virtual Desktop per ButtonClick

Tags: c#, winforms, virtual, desktop

I want to switch virtual Desktops via buttonpress, it should simply go to the next virtual Desktop. My first approach was trying to assign win+ctrl+Left/Right to a button, but since it doesn't loop that doesn't work, so I hope there is a way to check which desktop I am on and tell it to go to the other one.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Could you post your attempt so far? It helps if we have a starting point.

Comment: Hi! I don't have an attempt, I tried to figure out on how to fake button-presses but once I realized that won't work either way I dropped that. Now I only had the idea of if it's possible to somehow tell via C# to change Desktops.

Comment: Read the notes here: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417530/17034